# Are dependencies installed when I install an app from Ubuntu Software?

Tags: apt, package-management

This is just a question I have:
When I install an app from Ubuntu Software, it will have certain dependencies- are those installed along with the app? Also, if I download an rpm for another program which has the same dependencies, will installation work?

I am fairly new to Linux in general. After all, learning Windows first and then Linux is a bit like first learning how to drive an automatic and then a manual transmission car.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: As regards your first question: Yes. It wouldn't be possible to install it without dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apt is short for **A**dvanced **P**ackaging **T**ool, the package manager for Debian-based distributions. Ubuntu Software installs the same dependencies that would be installed if you installed the same package with apt from the terminal. rpm (RPM Package Manager, originally Red Hat Package Manager) is a different package manager from apt, so the dependency packages that are installed by rpm are not compatible with apt.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help! :)